# SIGSEGV error with 3D Plots

Tags: plotting, crash, ubuntu

I originally asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989102/mathematica-sigsegv-error-when-manipulating-3d-plots-with-mouse) but didn't get a satisfactory answer.

> I am using Mathematica 8.0.1.0 on Ubuntu 11.10. I created a 3D plot
>   from an `NDSolve` output and when I tried to move it about with my
>   mouse, Mathematica completely crashed and reported a `SIGSEGV` error.
>
> This error is totally reproducible. What is the reason for this? Is
>   this version of Mathematica not stable for Ubuntu 11.10?
>
> Any suggestions?

It doesn't really matter what I try to plot. Manipulating said plot with my mouse crashes mathematica. `Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]` for instance would crash if I moved the resulting plot around with my mouse pointer.

Edit 1:

The answer on stackoverflow "works". However, it makes mathematica run real slow for some reason.

I have submitted a ticket (TS 3197 in case there is someone here from Wolfram mathematica....) to the people at wolfram and have also tried pressing the issue but haven't received an answer.

Edit 2:
Graphics card information available from `SystemInformation[]` in Mathematica.

> Graphics Subsystem: OpenGL
>
> Typical Uses  3D graphics rotation
>
> Vendor    Tungsten Graphics, Inc
>
> Renderer  Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
>                 Version 2.1 Mesa 7.11
>
> Extensions 139 extensions
>
> Optimized 3D Transparency  False
>
> Support Information    http://support.wolfram.com/mathematica/graphics/subsystems

Comment: Working Ok in Mma 8.0, WinXP

Comment: So... is this a Ubuntu issue? Anyone?

Comment: Works fine on MM 8.04 OS-X Lion

Comment: It works fine on OS X actually... and windows... but I was wondering if anyone has had this issue with Ubuntu 11.10 and Mathematica 8.0.1.0?

Comment: It is useful to know whether it occurs on other platforms too. That way, some sources of bugs may be excluded.

Comment: Did you consider updating to 8.04? You never know.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries unfortunately, my university doesn't offer 8.04.... We've stopped at 8.01....

Comment: I use CentOS 5 and Fedora 15 & 16. With CentOS I had the same problem but only with graphics with many points. In Fedora 15 it always crash, but in Fedora 16 it doesn't. I tried with M7, M8, and M8.0.4. Updating from 8.0.1 to 8.0.4 doesn't help. Problem is not M but the system.

Comment: I think this is not "too localized" since Tech Support has seen the need to add an item to the knowledge base for this (though perhaps against a different video card.)

Comment: @DNA and you have installed the latest driver from http://intellinuxgraphics.org/download.html ? Maybe Ubuntu is using this driver anyway, but I would try it anyway.

Comment: @halirutan I will look into the _upgrading graphics card_ suggestion in a bit! It is Monday after all now and there are people brandishing whips!! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mathematica Knowledge Base has [an article](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3303) on this issue.

It´s caused by an error with open source graphics drivers. The mesa solution works by bypassing your graphics card and so will make things run a bit more slowly.

Comment: Yes, but this seems to make solving non linear pdes with `NDSolve` much slower than usual for some reason. I was under the impression that it would only affect the plotting routines...

Comment: As far as I understand, there really isn´t a reason that it should except for the fact that graphics in general will take more time. The only solution to this problem is to install a version of the driver for your graphics card which doesn´t have this issue. Oh, the joy of Linux.

Comment: I know what you mean! :) Thanks. This is the closest I've got to get this fixed. I'll live in eternal hope that Ubuntu11.10 gets updated to adapt.

Comment: @DNA: `NDSolve` is the kernel, `-mesa` is the frontend, and these are completely different processes, so they shouldn't interact too much, unless you're swapping from MESA eating into your main RAM or something.

Answer (score 8):

Building on Szabolcs' [hint](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3533/5),

> This issue is caused by a problematic graphics driver. The reason the
>   `mathematica -mesa` resolves this is that it bypasses the opengl code
>   which causes the crash.
>
> The error is most common with an Intel945 graphics card. You can try
>   reverting to an older version of the driver which doesn't have the
>   issue. Hopefully the driver will be updated at some point to fix this
>   issue.

This answer actually explains the most likely reason for your crash and provides a workaround.  If you need more, you need to send a crash log or debug backtrace to the [Wolfram support team](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Answer (score 7):

Start Mathematica with the command

```
mathematica -mesa
```

It will be a bit slow, but it probably won't crash.  This works for me.

About the rest of the incompatibilities with newer versions of Ubuntu, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Right it works... but what does `mathematica -mesa` do? The wolfram website certainly doesn't mention it.

Comment: @DNA I don't know and I don't remember where I found it.  It causes Mma to use http://www.mesa3d.org/ maybe?  Here on SO we are just users like you.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is caused by a problematic graphics driver. The reason the mathematica -mesa resolves this is that it bypasses the opengl code which causes the crash.

The error is most common with an Intel945 graphics card. You can try reverting to an older version of the driver which doesn't have the issue. Hopefully the driver will be updated at some point to fix this issue.