# Why does mathematica crash when I rotate a 3D graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, linux, crash, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SIGSEGV error with 3D Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/sigsegv-error-with-3d-plots)

I just recently installed **mathematica 8** on my linux machine, running ubuntu **11.10**
I decided to tun and test mathematica so while the terminal was still open I typed in mathematica and up it came. In mathematica I typed `Plot3D[{x+x*y},{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}];` into mathematica and a graph came up. I rotated it and for about a second I thought mathematica was doing well. It crashed and the window disappeared.

version of **mathematica** installed **8.0.4**

Comment: Do you have a [useful graphics-card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_family.html) installed then you should install the latest drivers too instead of running in *-mesa* mode.

Comment: If the links provide do not help, then we need definitely more information about your system. Most important the graphicscard, although I assume the Wolfram-support is a better place to ask. Can you execute this in Mma  `("OpenGL"/.SystemInformation["Devices","GraphicsDevices"]) /. ("Extensions" -> _) :> Sequence[]`

Comment: Does this post then get taken down?

Comment: You haven't even said if the solution(s) in the thread linked to were helpful to you...

Comment: yes they were helpful

Comment: Please see this article in the Wolfram Knowledge Base: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3303
The issue is with the open source graphics card driver, but the page provides a work around for the issue.