# AceFem keeps crashing immediately after plotting

Tags: plotting, acegen

I hope everybody is having a great day/night. 
I have generated an element on AceGen in which now I am running an analysis on through AceFem. Upon the evaluation of the AceFem notebook, the plot runs and renders, but Mathematica crashes immediately after.
I have:

1) Created the AceGen element in Debug mode so there should be no problems from that aspect.

2) Tried running a regular, non-AceFem/AceGen 3D plot on mathematica (as addressed on these posts [SIGSEGV error with 3D Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/sigsegv-error-with-3d-plots), [Why does mathematica crash when I rotate a 3D graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10838/why-does-mathematica-crash-when-i-rotate-a-3d-graph?noredirect=1&lq=1)) to check that nothing was wrong with my graphics  and it ran completely fine. I was able to rotate the image of the plot and Mathematica did not crash.

My machine details are:
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017)
3.1 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB. I am running Mathematica 12.
Any ideas/suggestions as to what may have caused this are welcomed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to say anything without a self-contained __minimal__ working example which produces the crash. Could you please edit your question to include it? What version of AceFEM are you using? What is the name or content of the error message that you get, if you get any?

Comment: @Pinti, do you mean link the whole code? Because I dont know where the problem is at all

Comment: No, don't post the whole code. Simply keep removing parts of the code that seem irrelevant. Remove some, then check if the problem disappeared. Keep repeating until you find the bit of code that caused the problem. Please read also these [guidelines](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example).